# show all likes count in each post django REST API

Tags: python, sql, django, rest

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class PostLike(models.Model):
    like = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Serializer.py

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField("like_count")
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields  = ("__all__")

    def like_count(self,obj):
        total_like = self.context.get("like_count")
        return total_like
```

views.py

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def allpost(request):
    id = request.data    
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    like_count = PostLike.objects.filter(post_id = id ).count()
    post_serializer = PostSerializer(post_list,many=True,context={"like_count":like_count})
    return Response(request,post_serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
 path('post/',views.allpost,name="post"),
]
```

output:

```
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "likes": 1,
  "title": "post 1",
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "likes": 1,
  "title": "post 2",
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "likes": 1,
  "title": "post 3",
},
]
```

db

```
id like post_id user_id
1   1     1      1
2   1     2      1
3   1     1      2
```

actually in my db likes are:
post 1 have 2 likes
post 2 have 1 like
post 3 don't have any like

i want to show this like this .
but it's showing the first post likes for every post .
how can i fix this .?
i know the problem in the like_count in view .
but i don't know what to put there instead of id .

sorry for my poor English
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use relationships, it helps a lot. Define a function in `Post` model, so serializer can get it easily.

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=150)

   def likes_count(self):
       return self.likes.all().count()

class PostLike(models.Model):
    like = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_likes')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='likes')
```

serializers.py:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields  = ["id", "title", "likes_count"]

    # That part you can delete
    # def like_count(self,obj):
    #     total_like = self.context.get("like_count")
    #     return total_like
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def allpost(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    post_serializer = PostSerializer(post_list, many=True)
    return Response(request, post_serializer.data)
```

## How relationships work:

We added `related_name='likes'` to `PostLike.post` field. That field is a connection as `ForeignKey` to the `Post` object that it referrences to. It means that is a kind of shortcut that you can use in the reverse way. It mostly behaves as a classic QuerySet but with only related objects (in this case `PostLikes` objects that have the given `Post` object.

Let's use your above models. Usage examples:

```
post = Post.objects.first()   # now 'post' is the first Post object

post.likes                    # it's just a relationship object, not helpful for now
post.likes.all()              # that gives QuerySet of all PostLike objects, that has this instance of Post as ForeignKey.
post.likes.filter(user__id=1) # that gives filtered QuerySet of PostLike with this instance of Post and instance of User with id 1
post.likes.last()             # that gives related PostLike object with highest pk/id - depending on ordering of course
post.likes.all().count()      # that gives the total count of all related objects
```

Read official docs, it's really rewarding. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#relationships

Comment: wow , thanks brother. you saved my lot of time. i don't how to say thank you to you . btw is the likes_count is working based on the related_name  ? . could you explain that please ?

Comment: Of course. I'll add more explanation in the post in a second.

Comment: I have updated my answer too based on another way to achieve the same thing. 
If you dont plan to reuse the likes_count a lot, you can have it they way I have written.

Answer (score -1):

You can make your serializer like this:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields  = ("__all__")

    def like_count(self, obj):
        total_like = PostLike.objects.filter(post_id=obj.id).count()
        return total_like
```

`views.py` would be

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def allpost(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    post_serializer = PostSerializer(post_list, many=True)
    return Response(request, post_serializer.data)
```

Comment: i tried , that's not working bro . it's showing the same result . look at the `id` bro . `id = request.data `.

Comment: Can you update your question with your urls.py ?

Comment: yup, updated ..

Comment: okay, so you are not sending any parameters in the url. 
Do you want to show the count of likes for all the posts or for just 1 post?

Comment: it's about listing all post  details. so i can't share any parameters in urls.py . instead of that  the API user gives a data . that is `id`

Comment: `urls` does not matter here

Comment: @NixonSparrow I just wanted to see if he is sending any parameters in the urls. To understand if he wants a per post count or for all.....

Shamsucm: I have updated the answer accordingly.